# How do I get these virtual domains working in Tomcat?

Tags: server, eclipse, tomcat, virtualhost

im new to ubuntu and tomcat moving away from windows and iis to create a website on AWs.  Im having problems trying to replicate what had running on my windows machine. I hope someone can clarify the following.

I've setup the following virtual domain;

```
dev.sitename.com
devimages.sitename.com
```

in my tomecat/conf/server.xml file i've setup the following one for each of the above virtual domains;

```
<Host name="dev.sitename.com" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" >
    <Context path="" docBase="/home/webapps/workspace/www_sitename_com/WebContent" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

problem i getting is that i cant seem to have both domain running simutiously as i did when running on IIS7. I dont understand why i can only run one instance of tomcat. Also if im viewing on of the above url's and i want to visit stackoverflow.com it stops the tomcat server. I dont understand why this is happening and how i can go about resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get multiple instance working follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808227/tomcat-7-instance-not-starting-on-ubuntu) link if you are looking to do the same.